# How do I join csv's from different blob blocks to be read by Azure machine's learning?

Tags: csv, azure, azure-blob-storage, cortana-intelligence, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm pretty new to azure blobs, and have this issue.
I have a blob block with 10+ csv files of the same format (same headers, etc). I want to join them together in order for the Azure Machine Learning workspace to read from them as one dataset. They are the only files in the blob block, and they're all csv's.

How do I join these large csv files together in the blob, without having to have a ML "join" for each file as it dynamically grows?

Comment: Do you have 10+ separate block blobs, or a single block blob? If they're all in one blob (which seems to be the case), how are they not already merged?

Comment: They're in the same blob, and I uploaded multiple csvs via C# to the same blob block. But in the future, we will be dumping multiple CSVs to the same blob to retrain the model as we go. I was wondering how to dynamically access all the blob's blocks and use all that data at once without having to make a reader per blob block.

Answer (score 1):

If you're always adding data to the end of the blob you should consider using append blobs. These blobs are specifically optimized for this use case and are simpler to use for the append-only scenario.

It sounds like from your clarification you want to get all the data in the block blob. A simple 'GET' on the blob should get the full blob and all of its CSVs -- there's a variety of download options in the C# lib since that's what you mentioned you were using. For downloads on block blobs, blocks aren't important and the data is viewed as one big thing. Blocks are more a unit for upload.